# How to change the object tag src with click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have an object tag

```
<object id ="video" data="immagini/trailer.png" onclick="trailer()"></object>
```

That I want to change data when I click on, I tried this in JavaScript but doesn't seem to work.

```
function trailer() {
    var sites = ['https://www.youtube.com/embed/CawVaHxWvnA']

    $('#video').src = sites;
}
```

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, if there is a better way just write it down.

Answer (score 1):

`.src` by itself is a DOM element property, you have a jQuery object, so use `attr`

```
$('#video').attr("src", sites);
```

You should be defining the click handler with jQuery tho, rather than using in-line handlers:

```
$('#video').click(function() {
    var sites = ['https://www.youtube.com/embed/CawVaHxWvnA']
    $(this).attr("src", sites);
});
```

Comment: seems it must be `sites[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The .prop() method is a convenient way to set the value of properties. Try this one.

```
function trailer() {
    var sites = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/CawVaHxWvnA";
    $('#video').prop( "disabled", sites);
}
```